# Matching 2 strings

Tags: javascript, html, web

Please have a look at the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script>
function count()
{
    var listOfWords, paragraph, listOfWordsArray, paragraphArray;
    var wordCounter=0;

    listOfWords = document.getElementById("wordsList").value;
    listOfWords = listOfWords.toUpperCase();

    //Split the words
    listOfWordsArray = listOfWords.split("/\r?\n/");



    //Get the paragrah text
    paragraph = document.getElementById("paragraph").value;
    paragraph = paragraph.toUpperCase();
    paragraphArray = paragraph.split(" ");


    //check whether paragraph contains words in list
    for(var i=0; i<paragraphArray.length; i++)
    {

        re = new RegExp("\\b"+paragraphArray[i]+"\\b","i");

        if(listOfWordsArray.match(re))
        {
            wordCounter++;
        }
    }

    window.alert("Number of Contains: "+wordCounter);
}
</script>

</head>


<body>
<center>
<p> Enter your Word List here </p>
<br />
<textarea id="wordsList" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>

<br />
<p>Enter your paragraph here</p>
<textarea id="paragraph" cols="100" rows="15"></textarea>

<br />
<br />
<button id="btn1"  onclick="count()">Calculate Percentage</button>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to iterate through the `paragraph` and check how many words in paragraph are inside the `listOfWords`. This should not omit words repetition , which means if there are 2 or more same words (ex: 2 "farmer" words) in paragraph, it should take it as 2 words and count and should not omit it because of the repentance.

Right now, my code is not providing any output, I don't know why.

Comment: Always check for errors in the developer console, please!

Comment: Also a fiddle would be helpful

Comment: I understand that English may not be your first language, but 'repentance' means something totally different. I think the word you want is 'repetition' ?

Comment: `match` is not a method of `Array`. A simple check with firebug can tell you that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the issues with the code that have been pointed out aside, I'd personally avoid the regex altogether and just run a check on the index:

```
function count() {
  var listOfWords, paragraph, listOfWordsArray, paragraphArray, wordCounter; 
  wordCounter = 0;
  listOfWordsArray = document.getElementById('wordsList').value.toUpperCase().split(' ');
  paragraphArray = document.getElementById('paragraph').value.toUpperCase().split(' ');
  for (var i = 0, l = paragraphArray.length; i < l; i++) {

    if (listOfWordsArray.indexOf(paragraphArray[i]) >= 0) {
      wordCounter++;
    }

  }
  window.alert('Number of Contains: ' + wordCounter);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a string to split, not a regular expression

```
listOfWordsArray = listOfWords.split("/\r?\n/");
```

You do not want the quotes

```
listOfWordsArray = listOfWords.split(/\r?\n/);
```

Comment: Just to clarify @epascarello 's point, don't surround the value between slashes / with quotes ". In javascript, a reg ex is specified just by a string enclosed in forward slashes without quote marks.

Comment: I used your advice as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First remove the quotes around the regex. Then try something like

```
for(var i=0;i<listOfWordsArray.length;i++)
{
    if(listOfWordsArray[i].match(paragraphArray[i])
    {
        wordCounter++;
    }
}
```

instead of

```
if(listOfWordsArray.match(re))
{
    wordCounter++;
}
```